# preg_match only letters, spaces and dashes and spaces allowed

Tags: php

i know that one condition that im currently using where it gives an error if $stringabc contains anything but numbers is :

```
if(preg_match("/[^0-9]/",$stringabc))
```

I want an if condition where it gives an error if $stringdef contains anything but letters, spaces and dashes (-).

Comment: Careful, define `letters`.. Is `ć` a letter to you? What about `א`? Do you mean just the ascii-range is what I'm getting to...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would be:

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-z\s-]/i',$stringabc))
```

for "anything but letters (a-z), spaces (\s, meaning any kind of whitespace), and dashes (-)".

To also allow numbers:

```
if(preg_match('/[^0-9a-z\s-]/i',$stringabc))
```

Comment: and if i wanted to add also anything but numbers it would be : if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\s-]/i',$stringabc)) ?

Comment: @Alexand657 It says to ignore case, meaning that `a-z` will also mean `A-Z`. You could drop the `i` but then you need to write `a-zA-Z`, which is longer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
preg_match("/[^a-z0-9 -]/i", $stringabc)
```

Comment: and if i wanted to change it to anything but letters, spaces, numbers and dashes?

Comment: @jeroen while doing that, you're introducing a bug, that even you (27k rep) overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop all whitespace, another way  you could do it is

```
preg_match("/^[a-z[[:space:]]-]/i",$stringabc);
```