# allow only space, letters and 1 dot in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

good day stackoverflow.

I have this code which allows only letters but I want to allow only spaces, letters and 1 dot.

```
if(!preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]/', $fullname)) {

}
```

thanks in advance

edit:
I want to allow this string

$fullname = "Mark E. Zuckerberg";
or 
$fullname = "Zuckerberg Mark E.";

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830745/preg-match-only-letters-spaces-and-dashes-and-spaces-allowed - simply use \s for space and change dash with dot in the given answer.

Comment: case insensitive match, so a-z will suffice instead a-zA-Z. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for details about the function.

Comment: ok thanks for the info sir :)

Comment: sure. hope it helps.

Comment: multiple spaces sir

Comment: You might want to use `if(preg_match('/^[\p{L}.\s\'-]+$/u', $fullname))` (then return true)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that will allow multiple periods, wont it?

Comment: @chris85: Yes it will. To allow only 1 dot, it should be `if(preg_match('/^[\p{L}\s\'-]+(?:\.[\p{L}\s\'-]+)?$/u', $fullname))`

Comment: The question body and title are in contrast here. The goal I think is for only 1 period to be allow. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Is the dot optional?

Comment: the dot is in the middle initial so isn't optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex like this:

```
'/[\w. ]*/'
```

If you want to allow only letters at start of string, you may use the regex like this:

```
'/^[\w]+[\w. ]*/'
```

**Edit:**

If you want to allow only 1 dot, you may use the next regex:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z ]*\.[a-zA-Z ]*$/'
```

If you want to allow only letters at start of string, you may use the regex like this:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z ]+\.[a-zA-Z ]*$/'
```

Comment: I want to allow letters, spaces and dot only as the title says.

Comment: So, use the first regular expression.

Comment: @MarverickM. Your title says "dot**s**"

Comment: `\w` is more than just letters.

Comment: the problem is what if they I have this?  Zuckerberg Mark E.?

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work `/^[a-zA-Z ]*\.[a-zA-Z ]*$/`, note that there is a space

Comment: it doesn't work. I have this `/[^a-zA-Z\s-]/` but I don't know the how can I add the dot there

Comment: `\.` would match the dot. Give a example of what string  ou are matching would be better